# How can I implement pagination on custom category page?

Tags: categories, loop, pagination

I have created a custom template page for every one of my categories. I am using a `foreach` loop in order to fetch the posts of this specific category in my page.

```
if (is_page()) {
    $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
    $posts = get_posts ("cat=$cat");
    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post); 
            the_title();
        endforeach;
    }
}
```

How can I implement pagination on posts with this, or other code, on custom pages?

Comment: Please do a site search on paginating custom queries. This topic has been handled numerous times

Answer (score 0):

It's far easier to use built-in loop functions such as pagination when you use a category template based on the template hierarchy.

You mentioned using the category ID to load posts into your custom template page, but if you instead name the template file based on the category ID, you can simply use the default WP loop, and include `<?php echo paginate_links(); ?>` to display the pagination you seek.

Proper Category Template Naming w/ ID:

```
category-{ID}.php
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to press forward using your existing custom category template naming, you can still utilize `paginate_links()` with `$args` that correspond with your query.

[Read More about paginate_links().](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Answer (score -1):

In Custom category page put this code , to work correctly to assign   `post_type' => 'post`

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 
    'prev_text' >' Previous',
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 2, 
    'paged' => $paged 
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Comment: Do not break the main query object

Answer (score -1):

**try this code just change category name**

```
  <?php
            $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'post',
            'category_name'  => 'blog',
              'orderby' => 'post_date',
              //'posts_per_page'=>'1'
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
           );
            query_posts( $args ); 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

         <?php  the_title(); ?>

       <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php // Wordpress Pagination
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                $links = paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text'    => '<',
                    'next_text'    => '>',
                    'type' => 'array'
                ) );
                if(!empty($links)){ ?>
                <ul class="pagination">
                        <?php

                        foreach($links as $link){
                            ?>
                            <li><?php echo $link; ?></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                        wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is totally incorrect. Also, never ever use `query_posts`. Unfortunately I can only downvote this once.

Comment: Also, please correct your formatting, your code is messy and hard to read